# Mocked object null during test method execution

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Using *JUnit* and *Mockito* I have a test object that is instantiated in the test, but when running the actual method it is null. Allow me to demonstrate:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class TestDataMgmtWebServiceImpl {
    @Mock
    CCRQueueDAO mockCCRQueueDAO;

    DataMgmtWebServiceImpl testObject = new DataMgmtWebServiceImpl();

...

    @Test
    public void testFindBySCAC() {
        QueueByScacReq testReq = new QueueByScacReq();
        testReq.setAfterThis(DatabasetoSOAP.calFromSQLDate(new Date(
            System.currentTimeMillis())));
        testReq.setScac("asdf");
        testReq.setStatus("fdsa");

        List<CCRQueueInfo> testInfos = TestObjects.createQueueInfoList(3);

        when(mockCCRQueueInfoDAO.getWithCriterion(testReq.getScac(),
            testReq.getStatus, SOAPToDatabase.sqlDateFromCal(testReq.getAfterThis(), null);
        QueueListResp actual = testObject.findChangeByScac(testReq);

        assertEquals(testinfos.get(1).getRequestorEmail(), 
            actual.getQueueList().get(1).getRequestorEmail());
    }
}
```

And `DataMgmtWebServiceImpl.findChangeReqByScac`

```
public QueueListResp findCHangeReqBySCAC(QueueByScacReq request) {
    QueueListResp response = new QueueListResp();
    for (CCRQueueInfo q : ccrQueueDAO.getWithCriterion(request.getScac(),
        request.getStatus, SOAPToDatabase.sqlDateFromCal(request.getAfterThis()), null) {
        response.getQueueList().add(DatabaseToSOAP.fromDBCCRQueueInfo(q));
    }
    return response;
}
```

in the test method `mockCCRQueueInfoDAO` is defined as a mock object. Unfortunately `ccrQueueDAO` in `findChangeReqBySCAC` is **null**, causing a `NullPointerException` when trying to access the `getWithCriterion` method.

Edit: this is where ccrQueueDAO is initialized in DataMgmtWebServiceImpl

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ccrQueueDAO = new CCRQueueDAO(props.getDbConnectionString(), 
        props.getDbLogin(), props.getDbPass());
}
```

Comment: Why would it be anything but `null` within the `DataMgmtWebServiceImpl` object??

Comment: Could you clarify where ccrQueueDAO is defined and initialized.  You have not posted that part of your code.

Comment: I should clarify that this runs find outside of the testing environment. Copying the init method into the original post now.

Comment: Where do you invoke `init`? Are these meant to be Spring beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocks aren't magic, they're just like any other Java object. If you want the `DataMgmtWebServiceImpl` class to use your mocked `CCRQueueDAO` object, then you'll need to pass the `mockCCRQueueDAO` object into `testObject` somehow. Most likely `DataMgmtWebServiceImpl` should have a constructor that takes a `CCRQueueDAO`, and you can construct it with the mocked field in a `@Before` method in your test.

You need to use a `@Before` method since it will run after the `MockitoJunitRunner` has initialized the `@Mock` fields. If you try to access a `@Mock` field during initialization of your class (e.g. in a field initializer) then the `@Mock` field will still have its default value (which is `null` for reference types).

Comment: Yup, I was worried it'd turn out I'd forgotten something simple. Thanks.